# Static property in Delphi

Tags: delphi, properties, static

I'm having a problem with static property Calendar.

```
type
  TDateTime = class(TObject)
  private
  class var fcalendar: TCalendar;
  class procedure SetCalendar(const Value: TCalendar);
  public
  class property Calendar: TCalendar read fcalendar write SetCalendar;
 end;

implementation

  class procedure TDateTime.SetCalendar(const Value: TCalendar);
  begin
    if Value <> nil then
    begin
      TDateTime.fcalendar := Value;
    end;
  end;
```

The error occurred at 7th line

> E2355 Class property accessor must be a class field or class static method

Comment: Note, declaring a class name with `TDateTime` may be confused with `System.TDateTime` type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the setter, and the error message explains exactly how you need to fix it: mark it as static.  This does mean that you can't use a virtual class method as an accessor, but you're not doing that anyway, so it shouldn't be a problem.

```
class procedure SetCalendar(const Value: TCalendar); static;
```

Comment: Except the error message doesn't explain how to _fix it_, since Delphi class methods are static by default, unless there is a keyword following the method declaration specifying otherwise, such as virtual or dynamic.  I've been using Delphi for 20 years and did not even know you could add the static keyword after a member declaration.  :(

Comment: @JonRobertson A class method receives a `TClass` reference to the current class as `Self`. A static method has no `Self`

Comment: I was not referring to "class methods".  That phrase can be confusing as all methods _belong_ to a class, but specifying that a Delphi method is a "class method" is closer to what I "normally" (outside of Delphi) call "static methods".  However, the answer refers to the "static" keyword placed after a method declaration, not the "class" keyboard placed before a method declaration.  What is the difference between a method that has "static;" after it and one that does not?

Comment: I see now there is a difference between "class methods" (declared with the "class" keyword before procedure or function) and "class static methods" (the same as prior, with the "static" keyword immediately after the declaration).  That is confusing when compared with Delphi's (and possibly Pascal's) old definition of static methods:  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Methods#Static_Methods. (Which states "Methods are by default static".  "Static methods" can be used to refer to two different things.  :(

Comment: See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Methods#Static_Methods.  Now explain the difference between most class methods, which are static (not virtual or dynamic) and class static methods.  Flipping the two words around has completely different meaning for Delphi, which confused me when I encountered this error message.

Comment: @JonRobertson Ah, I see what you mean.  Terminology confusion.  Ordinary methods are *instance methods*, not *class methods*--they're scoped to an object instance, and take an object instance as `Self`.  If they're not marked `virtual` or `dynamic`, they're dispatched statically rather than dynamically.  Methods marked as `class` methods are scoped to the class, and take a TClass reference as `Self`, rather than an object instance. They can also have static or virtual dispatch.  But class methods marked with the `static` directive have no `Self` and thus can't be dispatched virtually.